# i have make a database program in visual basic 2010.how i can set the 2 programs to see each other on 2 pc?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have make a database program in visual basic 2010.now the programm works fine but i want to install that program in another computer but how i can see the database from the other computer? for example i want to install the program in pc A and in another pc B.in A pc the user will have the ability to add,edit,delete info on database program.in computer B the user will have the abilyti only to see those records.My point is how i will fix the comunication between the 2 computers so computer B and user in computer B will have access in database that will be on computer A.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: i use sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a client and a server on one computer, you need to separate that.

You will need to install the program (client) on both computers (A,B) and setup the database on one computer (A). Configure the program other computer (B) to connect to the database on computer A. Computer A will be used as server for the clients on computer A and B. Computer A need to be always on. Or you may use third computer C, that will be the server and A and B will be the clients. You cannot do that with MS Access database. You need some kind of SQL server program (There are free databases you can use).

Check out client server architecture.

Be sure that you have configurable connection options in your client applications.

Comment: when i install the program also install the program and the databases that i have make in program.i made in programm when a user install the program on a pc,the program itself install the datadases.so i cant setup the databases just in oe pc in A pc. A pc it will be always on as a server,but if a computer does not have the prerequisite that the program need to have so to install an run poperly,then the program download sql server 2008 express. may be its better if i make a sharing folder database wich user can see the databases

Comment: or how i can Configure the program other computer (B) to connect to the database on computer A

Comment: You cannot do that with sharing folders. You need to have SQL server. You need to have configurable connection in your application (client). The problem is that now your connection (connection string) is hard coded. There must be a possibility to change that in your application. I don't know Visual Basic so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: i must rebuild again the app i think

Comment: Upvote answer if it is helpful or mark it as the solution if it solves your problem.